# What's a proper way to turn off genymotion emulator?

Tags: android, genymotion

Funny thing - I've always been shutting it down by closing emulator's window (X in upper-right corner, yes).

Now I somehow got interested if nothing is corrupted in emulator during that.

Surprisingly, nothing could be googled about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same problem (Windows 8.1, GenyMotion 2.1.1), and I sent an email to GenyMotion. Their answer:
 Genymotion
 Support (Genymobile)

Mar 28 15:00

Bonjour Yves,

Il n'est effectivement pas possible pour le moment d'arrêter un terminal virtuel 4.4.2 "proprement". Ceci est dû à un bug, que nous traiterons au plus vite.
En ce qui concerne de besoin de redémarrer Genymotion, le contournement est simple: il vous suffit de fermer la fenêtre Genymotion.
Vous serez averti dès que ce bug sera résolu!

Cordialement,

Damien
Genymotion Support Team

Translation (Google translation):

It is actually not possible at this time to stop a virtual terminal 4.4.2 "properly". This is due to a bug, which we treat as soon as possible. 
As regards the need to restart Genymotion, the workaround is simple: simply close the window Genymotion. 
You will be notified as soon as this bug will be solved!

My own solution: click on the red cross, use Task Manager or Process Explorer, and kill Process Tree "player.exe".

Hope this aids

Yves Ruin

Comment: I've been worried for long about emulators getting corrupted too,no proper way to close em for both geny motion or AVD , i guess X windows close isnt bad then.

Comment: Hold shut down button and then press Power off, I guess.