# How to turn off genymotion(alternative methods)?

Tags: genymotion

Basically I am trying to stop and restart the GenyMotion Emulator because it won't show up in the DDMS devices window or when I try to run an application. I tried this thread [What's a proper way to turn off genymotion emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596790/whats-a-proper-way-to-turn-off-genymotion-emulator) but there wasn't a process named player.exe when I loaded the Windows task manager. Does anyone know of any other way to stop this emulator? I tried resetting the adb but the emulator still showed on status. 
This is what the window looks like [image]

Comment: If you know this isn't the place, then why did you ask?

Comment: bc it was asked here previously http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596790/whats-a-proper-way-to-turn-off-genymotion-emulator

Comment: And I think this answer could benefit other programmers

Comment: @committedandroider - the cited question does not answer your question because you need an alternative method. Please stop making comments that encourage closing of your question. Either ask, or don't ask.

Comment: I am asking? just giving reasons why this question is a legitimate question to ask

Comment: wish somebody gave a solution cause it would have helped